# Are sundried tomatoes regulated in the EU?

Tags: tomatoes

There are different methods for drying tomatoes, and I suppose that using a dehydrator is most convenient in an industrial setting. Still, many dried tomatoes are sold as "sundried tomatoes". I have heard the skeptical opinion that these are probably tomatoes which were not dried in the sun, or maybe spent only a nominal amount of time in the sun.

Is there a legal norm prescribing what constitutes a "sundried tomato"? A special process to be followed? Maybe a minimal time prescribed for the tomatoes to spend in the sun (or at least under the sky outdoors, be it sunny or cloudy) after they have been picked?

I am interested in EU legislation, either on the level of the whole union or of states in it (I don't expect answers to list the details for each state if it is regulated on the national level).

Answer (score 1):

There's a ONU/CEE (in french) norm about dried tomatoes.

In PDF: 
http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trade/agr/standard/dry/dry_f/19DriedTomatoes_f.pdf

I am not certain if that is what you are looking for.

I did not find an English version.

Comment: Does it refer explicitly to *sundried* or just dried in general? The title simply says "séchées" and my French is not good enough to dig through pages of regulations.

Comment: @Stephie They're the same in French, always just séchées, no mention of sun.

Comment: @stephie It simply mentions that the label should (or can?) list a type, such as "sun dried" or "cubed", but the whole norm is not about sun dried tomatoes. Still, it is an important sign: if the norm about dried tomatoes does not say *when* a dried tomato counts as sun-dried, then the probability that there is no regulation about sun-dried grows.